# Скрыть меню при клике на пункт меню или документ

Tags: jquery

При клике на **button** открывается список. Нужно чтобы при клике на документ и при клике на пункт списка, сам список скрывался.

Но код работает через раз. При первом открытии списка, кликаю на документ и список скрывается, но уже больше не появляется. + не исчезает если кликать на пункт списка.

**Вопрос:** Как правильно скрыть меню при при клике на пункт этого меню?

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
    //do something

    var width = $(document).width();

    if (width < 768){
        $('.btn-trigger').click( function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var
                $this = $(this),
                pj = $this.closest('.project');

            if(!pj.hasClass('open')){
                pj.addClass('open');
            }else{
                pj.removeClass('open');
            }

        });
    }else if (width > 768){
        $('.project').removeClass('open');
    }


});

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
  var container = $('.project');
  if (container.has(e.target).length === 0){
    container.removeClass('open');
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.project {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn-trigger {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left: 20px;
}

.open ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="project">
  <a href="#" class="btn-trigger">button</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#i-1" class="link">item-1</a>      
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="google.com" class="link">item-2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#i-2" class="link">item-3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  
  <div id="i-1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi quo, saepe blanditiis deleniti ipsum harum delectus asperiores distinctio atque natus aliquam vitae recusandae nobis, ea, voluptatum optio est tenetur praesentium quidem quibusdam nulla sint? Accusantium asperiores amet reiciendis esse quasi reprehenderit vero ipsa, obcaecati dicta labore, illum corporis ea aut aliquid eius, nesciunt natus, voluptatum! Illum delectus cum quibusdam sequi in officiis rem ab architecto tenetur, necessitatibus molestiae, dolor eligendi laborum facere et quaerat molestias ipsam, quisquam voluptatibus maiores debitis. Quis praesentium animi, ipsum dicta ducimus labore inventore eum itaque alias officiis delectus eveniet nisi quos iusto harum obcaecati sunt reprehenderit necessitatibus, quisquam modi. Accusamus, magnam culpa tempore commodi! Neque id quas cupiditate, veniam at culpa nihil, consequatur, itaque, quo cumque reiciendis qui sit. Suscipit atque fuga culpa voluptas, expedita, delectus incidunt iste debitis sunt, accusantium libero dolore tempora neque vitae aperiam laudantium distinctio eveniet praesentium. Nam nobis natus ipsa iure, reprehenderit eius quo officia quasi ut. Dolorem reiciendis blanditiis totam neque repudiandae minus omnis odio assumenda accusantium, magni ea vel, temporibus dolorum aspernatur sed eveniet tenetur exercitationem praesentium dicta rerum, culpa. Odio necessitatibus officiis error minima earum nemo iure vero commodi inventore consequuntur, doloremque alias, ipsum fugiat veniam perspiciatis!
  </div>
  
  <div id="i-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic dolorum aperiam ex non excepturi aliquid itaque mollitia fugiat assumenda voluptatem nulla id iusto quis nemo sit molestias, temporibus corporis nostrum numquam iste, pariatur reprehenderit deserunt. Odio nihil distinctio voluptates error placeat nesciunt natus quasi, autem debitis illo eligendi nemo libero officia accusantium at quam magnam. Facere reprehenderit distinctio vitae corporis error unde consequatur ipsam, deserunt suscipit libero temporibus quam non vero vel, commodi enim magni corrupti dolore ab minus dolorum explicabo praesentium. Libero aperiam eos rem sint repellendus iure dolore minus hic, quasi, consectetur fuga voluptates necessitatibus. Vitae, quo. Velit!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: я Вам уже говорил, повторю еще раз: не назначайте обработчики событий внутри других обработчиков событий

Comment: Каждое выполнение строки `$('.btn-trigger').click( function(e){ ...` прикрепляет еще один обработчик. Все прикрепленные обработчики выполняются на click. При их четном количестве - выглядит так, что код ничего не делает.

Comment: или я это не Вам говорил? :)

Comment: @Igor, мне но все это не понятно! Да и ответ ваш не помог ничем

Comment: хорошо, объясните мне, пожалуйста, логику обработки события изменения размера окна - что должно происходить

Comment: @Igor, да можно без ресайза в принципе, меня больше волнует вопрос как скрывать меню при клике на пункт этого же меню вот и все!

Comment: `$(".link").click(function(e){ $(this).closest(".project").removeClass("open"); });`

Comment: посмотрите в ответе без `resize`

Comment: если хотите, мы можем подробнее обсудить вопрос "обработчиков внутри обработчиков"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не следует назначать обработчики событий внутри других обработчиков событий - без веской на то причины.

Каждое выполнение строки `$('.btn-trigger').click( function(e){ ...` прикрепляет еще один обработчик. Все прикрепленные обработчики выполняются на click. При их четном количестве страница в результате выглядит так, как будто код ничего не делает.

Оставим пока `resize` вне рассмотрения:

```js
$('.btn-trigger').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.project').toggleClass('open');
});

$(".link").click(function(e) { 
  $(this).closest(".project").removeClass("open"); 
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
  var container = $('.project');
  if (container.find('ul').has(e.target).length === 0 && 
      $(e.target).closest('.project ul').length === 0){
    container.removeClass('open');
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.project {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn-trigger {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left: 20px;
}

.open ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="project">
  <a href="#" class="btn-trigger">button</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#i-1" class="link">item-1</a>      
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="google.com" class="link">item-2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#i-2" class="link">item-3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  
  <div id="i-1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi quo, saepe blanditiis deleniti ipsum harum delectus asperiores distinctio atque natus aliquam vitae recusandae nobis, ea, voluptatum optio est tenetur praesentium quidem quibusdam nulla sint? Accusantium asperiores amet reiciendis esse quasi reprehenderit vero ipsa, obcaecati dicta labore, illum corporis ea aut aliquid eius, nesciunt natus, voluptatum! Illum delectus cum quibusdam sequi in officiis rem ab architecto tenetur, necessitatibus molestiae, dolor eligendi laborum facere et quaerat molestias ipsam, quisquam voluptatibus maiores debitis. Quis praesentium animi, ipsum dicta ducimus labore inventore eum itaque alias officiis delectus eveniet nisi quos iusto harum obcaecati sunt reprehenderit necessitatibus, quisquam modi. Accusamus, magnam culpa tempore commodi! Neque id quas cupiditate, veniam at culpa nihil, consequatur, itaque, quo cumque reiciendis qui sit. Suscipit atque fuga culpa voluptas, expedita, delectus incidunt iste debitis sunt, accusantium libero dolore tempora neque vitae aperiam laudantium distinctio eveniet praesentium. Nam nobis natus ipsa iure, reprehenderit eius quo officia quasi ut. Dolorem reiciendis blanditiis totam neque repudiandae minus omnis odio assumenda accusantium, magni ea vel, temporibus dolorum aspernatur sed eveniet tenetur exercitationem praesentium dicta rerum, culpa. Odio necessitatibus officiis error minima earum nemo iure vero commodi inventore consequuntur, doloremque alias, ipsum fugiat veniam perspiciatis!
  </div>
  
  <div id="i-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic dolorum aperiam ex non excepturi aliquid itaque mollitia fugiat assumenda voluptatem nulla id iusto quis nemo sit molestias, temporibus corporis nostrum numquam iste, pariatur reprehenderit deserunt. Odio nihil distinctio voluptates error placeat nesciunt natus quasi, autem debitis illo eligendi nemo libero officia accusantium at quam magnam. Facere reprehenderit distinctio vitae corporis error unde consequatur ipsam, deserunt suscipit libero temporibus quam non vero vel, commodi enim magni corrupti dolore ab minus dolorum explicabo praesentium. Libero aperiam eos rem sint repellendus iure dolore minus hic, quasi, consectetur fuga voluptates necessitatibus. Vitae, quo. Velit!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/BpOvqP

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы при клике в любом месте документа скрывалось меню?) ... на текст кликаю и не скрывается

Comment: пардон, не заметил, что div-ы с текстом находятся внутри div.project, сейчас

Comment: супер спасибо! Ну по "обработчиков внутри обработчиков" поняла что так делать нельзя ))